# disabling <a> parent link of a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
<li class="menu-229 menuparent menu-path-front even">
<a title="About" href="/tca/">about</a>
<ul style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">
</li>
```

Above is an example of how my dynamaically generated dropdown menu is setup.

The ul is the dropdown menu with links, however I want to disable the About a tag from being clickable. I dont want parents of dropdown to be a link.

I tried:

```
    $('.menuparent').click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault() // or return false;
});
```

but this code disables the dropdown menu links as well.

Sorry, forgot to mention this menu is generated by Drupal. I don't think I can touch it. I can only work with what I am given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this selector with [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/):

```
$('.menuparent > ul').prev('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Can only vote again in an hour, but I'll return and +1 when I can. @Adam: jsFiddle to show the working code -- http://jsfiddle.net/stealthyninja/hUbwb/2/

Comment: Amazing. Works without having to touch the css... which I edited to mention that I can't because a Drupal module called nice menu is generating it.

Answer (score 0):

A really simple approach would be to add a class to each of the parent items and use that exact code to target the parent class.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a title="About" href="/tca/" onClick="javascript:return false;">about</a>
```

Would this do it?

With an anchor tag the `onClick` event is evaluated before the `href` is actually followed. If the `onClick` event returns a `false` the `href` is not activated.